# Methods in Aspect class getting called twice for every method call in Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-aop

```
@Aspect
public class ControllerLogger {

    @Autowired
    InfobloxLogsMapper infobloxLogsMapper;

    Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ControllerLogger.class);
    LogResquestAndResponse logsMapper = new LogResquestAndResponse();

    private final RequestInformationProvider infoProvider;

    public ControllerLogger() {
        infoProvider = new RequestInformationProvider();
    }

    // for unit testing only
    ControllerLogger(Logger log, RequestInformationProvider infoProvider) {
                this.infoProvider = infoProvider;
                this.log = log;
            }

    @Before("execution(* com.tr.dco.fp.ipam.controller..*.*(..))")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        List<Object> paramList =Arrays.asList(joinPoint.getArgs());

        LogResquestAndResponse logs = infobloxLogsMapper.mapRequestResponsetoObject(logsMapper,paramList, infoProvider ,null, null );
        log.info("When=Before, User={}, Requester={}, Method={}, ParamList={}, Source= {}, Reference={} ", infoProvider.getCurrentUsername(),
                joinPoint.getSignature().toShortString(), paramList, infoProvider.getSourceSystem(), infoProvider.getReference());
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "execution(* com.tr.dco.fp.ipam.controller..*.*(..))", returning = "retVal")
    public void logAfter(JoinPoint joinPoint, ResponseEntity<?> retVal) {   
        List<Object> paramList =Arrays.asList(joinPoint.getArgs());
        LogResquestAndResponse logs = infobloxLogsMapper.mapRequestResponsetoObject(logsMapper,paramList, infoProvider ,retVal, null);
        List<LogResquestAndResponse> jsonList = new ArrayList<LogResquestAndResponse>();
        jsonList.add(logs);
        try{
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonlogs = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonList);
        saveToArongo(jsonlogs);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.warn(e.getMessage());
    }}

    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* com.tr.dco.fp.ipam.controller..*.*(..))", throwing = "ex")
    public void logError(JoinPoint joinPoint, Exception ex) {
        List<Object> paramList =Arrays.asList(joinPoint.getArgs());
        LogResquestAndResponse logs = infobloxLogsMapper.mapRequestResponsetoObject(logsMapper,paramList, infoProvider ,null, ex );
        List<LogResquestAndResponse> jsonList = new ArrayList<LogResquestAndResponse>();
        jsonList.add(logs);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();           
            String jsonlogs;
            try {
                jsonlogs = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonList);
                saveToArongo(jsonlogs);
            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


    public void saveToArongo(String jsonArray) {
        //saving in db
}
```

When I'm making an API call controller class. Firstly before method is getting executed, then actual method then After throwing method. After this again Before method is getting called followed by After returning method.
Not able to point out why it is getting called twice. Need help.

Comment: Could you please provide logs?

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue resolved.
There was a exception handler class included in the same package which was getting called in case of exception raised and which was again calling my before method.